# How to recursively download localhost:8080 to hard drive in a folder called "sample"?

Tags: wget, curl

It seems that `curl` doesn't have the ability to do that, and `wget` can do the job. (doing this on Mac OS X)

But

```
wget -r --no-parent http://localhost:8080
```

will download to a folder called `localhost:8080`

and

```
wget -r --no-parent http://localhost:8080 -P sample
```

will download to a folder called `sample/localhost:8080`

is there a way just to download to `sample` (without the `localhost:8080` part?)

P.S. I am downloading `localhost:8080` because node.js can serve my page that was written in React JS, but the "compiled file" `bundle.js` is no way to be found in my whole directory, so I just use `wget` to do the job and it also can download `index.html` and those files in `style/` or `css/` also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
wget -r http://localhost:8080 -P sample -nH
```

, where *-nH* (or --no-host-directories) will not create the host directory.